# Forgot to check "Notify daily of any new answers"

Tags: support, notifications

I just posted a question on ServerFault and I forgot to check the box next to `Notify [email address] daily of any new answers`. Now I can't seem to find a way to track that question via email. Am I missing something or is that a one-shot deal?

Comment: Go back to the question and scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page. What do you see?

Comment: @ChrisF - why not post that as an answer? I for one would vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go back to the question and scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page. What do you see?

Comment: Ok sorry. I'm an idiot!